# conexión JDBC con postgresql remoto

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

quiero saber si así se hace una conexión a servidor de potsgres desde java? ya que quiero conectarme asi un servidor externo que no es local

```
package Modelo2;
import java.sql.Connection; import java.sql.DriverManager;

public class Conexion2 {  
    Connection conexion;
    
    public Connection conectar(String base) {
    
        String url="jdbc:postgresql://198.12.150.200:8384/"+base;
        String usuario="pruebaserver";
        String clave="contrase4587989";
        
        try {
            Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
            conexion=DriverManager.getConnection(url,usuario,clave);
        }catch (Exception e) {
            
        }
        return conexion;        
    }
}
```

Comment: Al parece esta correcto la forma de  conectarte a un servidor de PostgreSQL desde Java.
Tambien tienes que tener en cuanta algunas cosas :
1:Que las credenciales como usuario y clave estes correctas
2:Asegúrate de que el servidor PostgreSQL al que intentas conectarte está configurado para permitir conexiones remotas.
3:verificar la ip y el puerto que sean correctos.
eso seria todo pero en conclusion si esta bien :D

Comment: Hola JAPS, hacer varias veces la misma pregunta, no está bien visto, te recomiendo que elimines alguna de tus preguntas para evitar recibir votos negativos, aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos.

Comment: Recuerda que siempre que necesites, puedes editar tu pregunta para agregar algo, o hacer alguna aclaración.

Answer (score 0):

Está bien, con algunos comentarios.

1. En el cuerpo de la excepción te conviene imprimir el stack trace, idealmente con algún tipo de herramienta de logging, pero para pruebas, `e.printStackTrace()` es suficiente. Esto va a ser necesario para que si no se conecte, sepas por qué, quizás mejor aún tu método debería propagar la excepción, pero te conviene solo propagar las checkeadas, en este caso `SQLException`.
2. En las versiones actuales de java (desde JDBC 4.0, con java 6), no es necesario precargar la clase del driver, es decir, puedes eliminar la línea

```java
Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
```

3. Para código de prueba está bien, pero el nombre de usuario y contraseña deben cargarse desde algún lugar que no quede con el código fuente.